# Losing image quality when resize in PictureBox Form C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, frameworks

I have a form without border and need show only a image in the corner of window, the picture dimentions are 9567 x 18012 and size is 62 MB, i use a PictureBox in a form when resize the quality loss, why?, i a need a thirdparty library for show a image to big in dimensions and size?

The left image is a PictureBox  with my image and the right is the original image with te information

[image: The left image is a PictureBox with my image and the right is the original image with te information]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to reduce the image size.

```
public void SetPictureBoxImage(string path)
{
    Image myImage = Image.FromFile(path, true);
    int width = 500;
    double ratio = (double)myImage.Width / (double)myImage.Height;
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(width / ratio);
           
    if (height > width)
    {
        ratio = (double)myImage.Height / (double)myImage.Width;
        height = width;
        width = Convert.ToInt32(height / ratio);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = ResizeImage(myImage, width, height);
}
```

Resize Method

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
   var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
   var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

   destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
   using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
   {
      graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
      graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
      graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
      graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
      graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

      using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
      {
          wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
          graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
      }
   }

   return destImage;
}
```